# Ubuntu 18.04 Suspend Hangs Sometimes on Cryptsetup

Tags: suspend

My PC is running Ubuntu 18.04 with default Ubuntu full disk encryption enabled. Occasionally, when I try to suspend my PC, it hangs and shows “cryptsetup: sda3_crypt set up successfully” and the screen is stuck there. Eventually I have to force shut down my PC. Any ideas on how to fix this?